# \w in Ruby Regular Expression matches Chinese characters

Tags: ruby, regex

I use the code below:

```
puts "matched"  if "中国" =~ /\w+/
```

it puts `"matched"` and surprised me, since "中国" is two Chinese characters, it doesn't any of 0-9, a-z, A-Z and _, but why it outputs "matched".

Could somebody give me some clues?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to use regex for utf8 in ruby](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256822/how-to-use-regex-for-utf8-in-ruby)

Comment: they are not the same dialog, the link you pointed discusses how to validate Chinese characters, my issue is why \w matches UTF-8 Chinese characters.

Comment: 不同的引擎有不同的解释吧，.net等引擎视中文为\w，所有的浏览器所使用的引擎都将中文视为\W，个人赞同前者。

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm not sure of the exact flavor of regex that Ruby uses, but this isn't just a Ruby aberration as .net works this way as well. MSDN [says this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972966.aspx) about it:

> \w
>   Matches any word character. For
>   non-Unicode and ECMAScript
>   implementations, this is the same as
>   [a-zA-Z_0-9]. In Unicode categories,
>   this is the same as
>   [\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}].

So it's not the case that `\w` necessarily just means `[a-zA-Z_0-9]` - it (and other operators) operate differently on Unicode strings compared to how they do for Ascii ones.

This still makes it different from `.` though, as `\w` wouldn't match punctuation characters (sort of - see the \p{Lo} list below though) , spaces, new lines and various other non-word symbols.

As for what exactly `\p{Ll}\p{Lu}\p{Lt}\p{Lo}\p{Nd}\p{Pc}` does match, you can see on a Unicode reference list:

- \p{Ll} [Lowercase Unicode letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Ll/list.htm)
- \p{Lu} [Uppercase Unicode letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lu/list.htm)
- \p{Lt} [Titlecase Unicode letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lt/list.htm)
- \p{Lo} [Other Unicode letter](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Lo/list.htm)
- \p{Nd} [Decimal, number](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Nd/list.htm)
- \p{Pc} ["Punctuation, connector"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/category/Pc/list.htm)

Comment: Actually `\w` did not work for me for chinese or accented characters, but `\p{Word}` did

Answer (score 3):

[Oniguruma](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/oniguruma/), which is the regex engine in Ruby 1.9+, [defines `\w`](http://oniguruma.rubyforge.org/svn/Syntax.txt) as:

```
[\w]       word character

           Not Unicode:
           * alphanumeric, "_" and multibyte char. 
           Unicode:
           * General_Category -- (Letter|Mark|Number|Connector_Punctuation)
```

In 1.9+, Ruby knows if the string has Unicode characters, and automatically switches to use Unicode mode for pattern matching.