# How do you use unicode characters within a regular expression in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, regex, unicode

I am attempting to write a line of code that will take a line of japanese text and delete a certain set of characters. However I am having trouble with using unicode characters inside of the regular expression.

I am currently using `text.gsub(/《.*?》/u, '')` but I get the error

```
'gsub': invalid byte sequence in Windows-31J (Argument error)
```

Can anyone tell me what I am doing incorrectly?

Example text : その仕草《しぐさ》があまりに無造作《むぞうさ》だったので

Expected result: その仕草があまりに無造作だったので

Thanks

edit:  `# encoding: utf-8` is present at the top of the script.

Comment: Yes I have. Sorry forgot I to mention it.

Comment: I've tried out your example in `irb` and got the expected result. Seems that the problem is not the regular expression, but the encoding of `text`. Where does the `text` come from? Read from a file?

Comment: You can take a look at this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/256822/how-to-use-regex-for-utf8-in-ruby

Comment: I am indeed grabbing the text from a file, LimboPeng

Comment: Is the file itself being saved as UTF-8 encoding?  This code works just fine on my end, by the way, so I think something is up with your local setup.

Comment: The file is in UTF-8 encoding according to Notepad++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
text.encode('utf-8', 'utf-8').gsub(/《.*?》/u, '')
```

Comment: Please explain why, because what you have there makes no sense to me.

Comment: Why isn’t it already that way? Is this the general Ruby bug of strings never being decoded properly? You should not have to do this.

Comment: @tchrist It is not necessarily true when you read the text from a external file - its encoding may not be UTF-8.